# Missing triangles when drawing a sphere

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, geometry

I'm trying to draw a sphere with openGL, but I can't find my mistake...

Only half of the triangles are drawn, like [here in the picture](http://i58.tinypic.com/f1f4hv.jpg).

Here is my algorithm so far:

```
// The angle step used in iteration
float a = (2.0f*M_PI)/8.0;

float c = 0.0f;

for (float theta = 0.0f; theta < 2.0f*M_PI; theta += a, c += a/2.0f)

for (float phi = 0.0f; phi < 2.0f*M_PI; phi += a) {
    // Here something is missing...

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    float p_1[3] = {sin(theta)*cos(phi+c), 
    sin(theta)*sin(phi+c), 
    cos(theta)};
    glVertex3f(p_1[0], p_1[1], p_1[2]);

    float p_3[3] = {sin(theta+a)*cos(phi+c+a/2.0f), 
    sin(theta+a)*sin(phi+c+a/2.0f), 
    cos(theta+a)};
    glVertex3f(p_3[0], p_3[1], p_3[2]);


    float p_2[3] = {sin(theta)*cos(phi+c+a), 
    sin(theta)*sin(phi+c+a), 
    cos(theta)};
    glVertex3f(p_2[0], p_2[1], p_2[2]);   

    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: pi/4 is way too huge (45 degrees) use a smaller increment

Comment: I'm sorry, I forget to mention.
Even if I set a smaller increment, 
half of the triangles of the sphere is missing...

Comment: Could it be, that half of the triangles are defined counter clockwise and thats why they are culled off?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that half your triangles have the wrong orientation?
http://math.hws.edu/graphicsnotes/c3/s2.html

Comment: I don't think it's the winding. Looks like the code is in fact only drawing a triangle for each patch, which needs to have the shape of a quad. There are only 3 `glVertex3f` calls in the loop, and it needs 4 of them. The way the angle increments are applied also looks inconsistent. And it's using float comparisons for terminating the loop. Lots of problems in this code, but the winding isn't one of them, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with this code:

1. Using floating point tests for loop condition. Keep in mind that float calculations are not exact. You have about a 50% chance of going through the loop one more time than you intended.
2. With standard spherical coordinates, the range of theta should be from 0..pi, not 0..2*pi.
3. You need to generate a quad inside the loop, not a triangle. Picture a map. If you look at the area between two lines of longitude and two lines of latitude, it has 4 corners.
4. I don't understand what your value `c` is doing. Not sure if this is a problem, or if I'm just not getting it.
5. Not a correctness problem, but you can place your `glBegin` and `glEnd` calls outside the loop.